# PHP Make mySQL query appear as array

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$urls = array(
    0 => array('url' => 'phpclasses.org', 'keyword' => 'phpclass'),
    1 => array('url' => 'phpclasses.org', 'keyword' => 'php'),
    2 => array('url' => 'php.com', 'keyword' => 'php')
);
```

My problem is that I want to replace the data above with data that I'm getting from the database.

I have a table with the following fields:

```
id(auto), url and keyword.
```

Then I connect to the database:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM my_table");
```

My question is how can I create a mysqli query that would get the data in the format of the array above?

Comment: How do you get your data from mysql in the first place?

Comment: It looks like the indexes line-up with the column names so you just need to iterate over your result set and add each row from the database to an array. If the column names do not match your desired indexes then you can use `AS` to essentially rename the column names for your query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("DATABASE");

$urls = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$urls[] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'keyword' => $row['keyword']);
}

var_dump($urls);
?>
```

With your code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM my_table");

$urls = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$urls[] = array('url' => $row['from_id'], 'keyword' => $row['to_id']);
}

var_dump($urls);
?>
```

Vote up if the answer help you.

Comment: What if one of the rows is deleted from the database and you try to reach the id through the index of the array? This example would be inconsistent.

Comment: You defined only the number of array with ID, he dont told us to define it ;) and if rows deleted from database he will be removed too from the array !

Comment: Yes let's just ignore everything and just do no effort to help people, because "he dont told us to define it" what is already defined.

Comment: ?? What are you talking about ! You usede the same code that i did ! u added $row['id'] and it's not important to define the array !

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code replicates your array, the the index of the array is the `id` field from the database, and the other values are inside of the array.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM my_table");

$urls = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $urls[$row['id']] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'keyword' => $row['keyword']);
}

var_dump($urls);
?>
```